# How to: Emacs and FTP?

Tags: emacs, ftp

Can someone advise me as to how to get FTP working in emacs? It doesn't have to be SFTP, etc, just plain old FTP. I've tried multiple times, and never could get it working. I think the closest I got one time was having an FTP prompt in emacs, but It wouldn't list any dirs. The only think tying me to an IDE is the remote directory tree on the left. If I could just somehow list, get, edit, and put (preferably as soon as I hit save, automagically) files /inside/ of emacs, without having to use Filezilla / FireFTP / etc, then I'd be super happy!

tl;dr; Enable FTP browsing, etc, in emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ange-ftp will do ftp/sftp for you... look here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp

(Use Tramp too, which wraps Ange-ftp)

Comment: I've messed with that, but it is completely confusing. Plus it looks like I have to know the exact file name / location for that. I was hoping there'd be a way to browse a server.

Comment: I really'd like to find something that works just like Dired (C-x d), and lets me browse that way.

Comment: @Josh, are you after dired style browsing of FTP/SFTP?

Comment: .... I see that you are :) I hear that ange-ftp + tramp will give you dired mode, although I don't use it so I can't confirm.

Comment: What problems are you having with ange-ftp ?

Comment: @slomojo Honestly, I don't know where to start with it. It seems overwhelming. I think I have tramp and angeftp, as I mentioned, it seems to load the module, but then the process dies.

Comment: Unfortunately my corporate firewall blocks SSH/SFTP/FTP so I can't test this out for you without setting up an internal FTP server, which I suppose I could do a bit later ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like [`TRAMP`](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/TrampMode).

```
It allows you transparent access to files on remote
access. “Transparent” means that usually the user doesn’t have to
worry about anything. All that changes is the filename convention
to indicate that the file resides on a remote system.
```

Comment: Tramp hands over it's FTP access to Ange-ftp (which in turn hands it over to an external console style ftp client (e.g. gnu ftp))

Comment: I try: C-x C-f; /josh:pass@host.com , and it says: "Process *tramp/scp josh* exited abnormally with code 255" & (at bottom) "File error: process died"

Comment: that address style will have Tramp attempt an ssh/scp transfer, you need to use the protocol header ftp:// - if your host is SFTP it should work with tramp (without ange) if it's just FTP, you need ange installed (and configured!) too.

Comment: What exactly should I type in? I type C-x C-f, then ftp: // josh:pass@host.com (no space on the ftp protocol, the formatter is being weird on the page), and it wraps it like: Find file: {ftp:/} /josh:pass@host.com, then dies with the same error.

Comment: C-x C-f ... minibuffer -> Find File: `ftp://josh:pass@host.com/` should go to the root folder if ange-ftp is configured right. (did you setup the ftp client for ange?)

Comment: Um, how do I set up the client?

Comment: C-x C-f /ftp:user@host:/path/

Comment: @cYrus Brilliant! Works like a freaking charm!!!

Comment: @cYrus Is there a way to automate that? Maybe a keybinding of C-x C-SOMETHING will auto login, w/ password?

Comment: I don't know about passwords, you should read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/). However, you can add something like `(global-set-key (kbd "C-<f1>") (lambda () (interactive) (find-file "/ftp:user@host:/path/")))` to your `~/.emacs` to bind that login to C-F1, but it will ask you the password as well.

Answer (score -1):

I've had luck running the ftp that comes w/cygwin64 but I would like to find a more light-weight solution: the installation of cygwin64 clocks in at about 3 GB.